# ¿Por qué el preprocesador interpreta la palabra “linux” como la constante “1”?

Tags: linux, c

> Pregunta original: [Why does the C preprocessor interpret the word “linux” as the constant “1”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210935/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-interpret-the-word-linux-as-the-constant-1) [de ahmedaly50](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2851929/ahmedaly50)

¿Por qué el preprocesador en GCC interpreta la palabra `linux` como la constante `1`?

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int linux = 5;
return 0;
}
```

Resultado de `$ gcc -E test.c` (para después de la etapa de pre-procesador):

```
int main(void)
{
int 1 = 5;
return 0;
}
```

Lo que, por supuesto, produce un error.

(Por cierto:  No hay un `#define linux` en el archivo stdio.h)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

La compilación de programas en C y C++ no supone una etapa simple, es decir, el código fuente se acepta como entrada y el ejecutable se emite como salida. En realidad, el compilador es solo una pieza (aunque la pieza principal) de un proceso que empieza con el preprocesador, sigue con el compilador en sí, y termina con el enlazador (*linker*). A esta cadena de programas muchas veces se la llamada, de forma abreviada, *toolchain*, ya que son precisamente una cadena de herramientas que se dispara para finalmente generar un programa ejecutable. Esta es, por cierto, la filosofía de trabajo en UNIX, de forma que pequeñas herramientas resuelven problemas relativamente simples, y su concatenación acaba generando un resultado que puede ser tan complejo como un programa ejecutable. Dentro de esta cadena, el preprocesador **CPP**, define una serie de macros que están disponibles antes de compilar nada. Se trata de las llamadas macros predefinidas.

Estas macros ayudan en el proceso de compilación (por ejemplo, `__FILE__` siempre lleva el nombre del archivo que están compilando), otras ayudan a saber cuál es el objetivo de la compilación (`__STDC__` vale uno si se está compilando C estándar).

Con el tiempo, estas macros se volvieron tan populares que todo el mundo las usaba, y por tanto se estandarizaron. Así, hay unas macros predefinidas que por ejemplo toda *toolchain* para C tiene que tener. Durante el proceso de estandarización, se llegó a la conclusión de que lo mejor era que estas macros estuvieran precedidas, así como seguidas, de doble subrayado. Por ejemplo, la macro `linux` pasó a ser `__linux__`. De esta forma, el usuario nunca escogería por error el nombre de una macro predefinida, lo cual llevaría a problemas como el que describes.

La macro `linux`, así como `unix` se utilizaba como ayuda para saber para qué sistema se estaba compilando. Con el tiempo, pasaron a ser transformadas según lo que indicaba el estándar, pero se mantienen en la compilación por defecto para servir a aquellos programas antiguos que todavía cuentan con la presencia de estas macros para ser compilados correctamente.

Para saber las macros predefinidas, puedes invocar **cpp** (*C Pre-Processor*, el preprocesador de C, nada que ver con C++) con las opciones `-dM` (importante respetar mayúsculas y minúsculas) para que te liste todas las macros por defecto. Como no querrás aportar un archivo, puedes hacerlo con `/dev/null`.

```
$ cpp -dM /dev/null
#define __unix__ 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define unix 1
#define linux 1
#define __x86_64 1
...
```

Entre otras muchas, en mi máquina (Ubuntu 15.10 x64) están definidas las macros que lo identifican como linux, como variante (estándar POSIX) de unix, y como arquitectura de 64 bits. Así...

```
$ cpp -dM /dev/null | grep linux
#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define linux 1
```

Con `grep` podemos filtrar el resultado para que aparezcan única y exclusivamente las macros que tengan como identificador o parte de su identificador la palabra `linux`. Vemos que están todas, las antiguas y las nuevas.

¿Qué pasa si indicamos a CPP que deseamos compilar para un estándar de C, como por ejemplo el del 1999?

```
$ cpp -dM /dev/null -std=c99 | grep linux
#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
```

Como le hemos pedido a CPP que sea más estricto, solo aparecen las macros predefinidas que realmente forman parte del estándar.

Las [macros predefinidas estándar](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), así como las [macros predefinidas propias de **CPP**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros) están documentadas en el [manual del preprocesador](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

Espero que esto responda a tu pregunta.

Comment: Sabia mas o menos de que iba la historia, pero ni por asomo de tantos detalles, muy interesantes son los que aportas en tu respuesta gracias por ella Saludos